# Agrupamento e Soma no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu tenho um registro de Clientes

```
ID    NOME  GRUPO
2033  JOAO  FORNECEDORES
2044  MARIA MANUTENCAO
2055  JOSE  FORNECEDORES
```

E tenho um registro de compras efetuado por cada cliente

```
ID_CLIENTE  VALOR_COMPRA
2033        4.000
2033        1.130
2044        8.930
2044        4.430
2055        4.023
```

**Como realizar uma consulta que me retorne o gasto por grupo?**

```
GRUPO         TOTAL_GASTO
FORNECEDORES  9.153
MANUTENCAO    13.360
```

**E por cada cliente?**

```
   CLIENTE  TOTAL_GASTO
   JOAO     5.130
   MARIA    13.360
   JOSE     4.023
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `GROUP_BY` em conjunto com a função `SUM`:

```
SELECT cli.grupo,
       SUM(com.valor_compra) AS total_gasto
  FROM clientes cli
       INNER JOIN compras com ON com.id_cliente = cli.id
 GROUP BY cli.grupo;
```

No caso do cliente:

```
SELECT cli.nome AS cliente,
       SUM(com.valor_compra) AS total_gasto
  FROM clientes cli
       INNER JOIN compras com ON com.id_cliente = cli.id
 GROUP BY cli.grupo
```

> [GROUP BY](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html)

> A GROUP BY clause groups a result into subsets that have matching values for one or more columns.

Em tradução livre:

> A cláusula GROUP BY agrupa o resultado em grupos que correspondam a uma ou mais colunas.

---

> [SUM](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj13083.html)

> SUM is an aggregate function that evaluates the sum of the expression over a set of rows.

Em tradução livre:

> SUM é uma função agregada que resolve a soma da expressão sobre o conjunto de linhas.